# Set twig variable to json file as an include

Tags: json, twig

I have created twig templates and save all the content in a jsonfile. Like this:

Json Data:

```
{% set contentElements = {
     "json structur": {....} 
     "json structur": {....} 
%}
```

Unfortunately over the years the json files has become bigger and bigger.
So i want to splitt the json data into snippets.

It is possible to set the variable contentElements to an include?

It is not working but something like this:

```
 {% set contentElements = include"content.json "%}
```

Its an static HTML Project.

Answer (score 7):

To capture chunks of text it is better to use the `{% set var %}`/`{% endset %}` tag. This allows you to assign "larger" amount of data to a variable. It's also possible to pass content from another file to the variable this way in combination with `include`.

```
{% set json %}
    {% include "content.json" %}
{% endset %}

{{ json }}
```

*(sidenote: Content captured as chunk is being treated as safe)*

Comment: Good answer @DarkBee, you may want to explain details of what it does and [link to docs](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/set.html#set) so the OP has a good understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @Alvin it was to hot in the office to create an extended answer :-)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately it is not working.
"unexpected end of tag "set"  in line 3. maybe it has got a problem with endset?

I am not using twig - it is swig. Maybe swig does not know this code?