# How can I use a separate json file as a variable within my twig file?

Tags: json, twig

I have a twig file in which I have included json which is set as a variable and accessed within the file.

```
{% set header_links = {
    'study': {
        'main_menu': {
            'menu_links': [
                {
                    'title' :  "Link 1",
                    'url'   :  "https://www.test.com"
                },
                {
                    'title' :  "Link 2",
                    'url'   :  "https://www.test.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
%}
```

I can then easily call the values within the twig file which is great

```
{{ header_links.study.main_menu }}
<ul>
{% for link in header_links.study.main_menu.menu_links %}
 <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However I'd like to keep the json header_links data in a separate json file and include it into the twig so that I can keep the page neat.

I've put the json into a new file `header_links.json`

And then tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654948/set-twig-variable-to-json-file-as-an-include) to pull it into my twig file

```
{% set header_links %}
    {% include "header_links.json" %}
{% endset %}
```

And was hoping I could then use `header_link`  variable as previously to access the data.

This isn't working for me. Does anyone know how I might do this or am I using Twig incorrectly?

Any help much appreaciated thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it work if you just ` {% include "header_links.json" %}`? Putting this in `{% set header_links %}` seems like doubling the work (inside of the "json" file you have `{% set header_links = { ...` as well.

Comment: "*This isn't working for me*" - What is not working?

Comment: When I use:


`{% set header_links %}
    {% include "header_links.json" %}
{% endset %}`

to include the header_links.json file into my twig file,
then I cannot access the data in the json file within the twig file.

So this should work in my twig file, but doesn't:

`<ul>
{% for link in header_links.study.main_menu.menu_links %}
 <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>`